# words between polar antonyms - what are they called?

Tags: terminology, antonymy

Polar antonyms, (graded antonyms?) are those that are opposite of each other, yet may possess a range of words/states between them;
Tiny, small, medium, large, huge.

Is there a word or term for any words that fall between the two poles/end of the spectrum/range?
Are there any references/resources that cover such words (is there a set of rules, or is it arbitrary or discretionary?)?

I've googled and binged, but found nothing useful so far, (nor the search here).
The only thing I can think of is looking for words that share the same concept (such as 'size' for the above) - but that seems a lot of work, and I'm not seeing a lot of resources there either (WordNet only?).

Thank you for your time and any assistance you can give me.

Comment: Generally they're simply called 'non-polar'. English has at least one test for polar adjectives (and therefore non-polar ones as well): the adverb _absolutely_ has the property that it can only modify a polar adjective. So _absolutely freezing/boiling_, but not **absolutely hot/cold/warm/cool/lukewarm*. And, while _mad_ has two senses -- non-polar 'angry' and polar 'insane' -- _absolutely mad_ can only mean 'absolutely insane'.

Comment: @jlawler - wow, thank you. Didn't know of the test, and thanks for the term as well.